# Save table in viewer as jpg or png in R

Tags: r

I am trying to save my table (created via tab_model) in the viewer of R. Nothing I have found so far works as it is not a dataframe. I am getting messages like

> $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Has anyone an idea how I could save it nevertheless?

Comment: Can you amend your question with some self-contained reproducible code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
library(sjPlot)
library(webshot)
tab_model(dat, file = "plot.html")
#save as image
webshot("plot.html", "plot.png")
```